# A formal procedure to successfully create a tree over $2^k$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph $G$ with $2^k$ vertices and initially zero edges. I am trying to successfully adding edges to end up with a tree with $2^k-1$ edges. Each time I add $2^{k-i}$ edges for $i={1,2,..,k}$.

I see I end up with $2^k-1$ edges but I am unable to find a formal method/procedure to create it and ensuring the result is actually a tree. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Start by labeling your verts from $1$ to $2^k$; on step $i$, for each $j$ from $2^{(k-j)}+1$ to $2^{(k-j+1)}$, add an edge from $j$ to $\lfloor j/2\rfloor$.  You should be able to show that this adds precisely $2^k-1$ edges (hint: we add edges from every number but 1, and add exactly one edge from each of those numbers), and that no cycles are formed (hint: every edge runs to a smaller number).